# Makefile for shared library that only compiles changed files?

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries

I am working on a project where I am creating a .so object as my output that contains several operators for use in another program. I was given a Makefile that works just fine, except it always recompiles every file whenever I run make. Originally this was not an issue, but now that there are upwards of five or more operators in the library, running make is prohibitively slow. The trouble is that for the life of me, I can't figure out how to change this Makefile into one that behaves the way I want since I've never dealt with Makefiles in this format before:

```
BOOST_LOCATION=/usr/local/boost_1_54_0

CFLAGS=-pedantic -W -Wextra -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-long -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -Wno-system-headers -isystem -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -ggdb3  -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
INC=-I. -DPROJECT_ROOT="\"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)\"" -I"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)/include" -I"$(BOOST_LOCATION)"
LIBS=-L"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)/lib" -shared -Wl,-soname,libname.so -L. -lm

all:
    @if test ! -d "$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)"; then echo  "Error. Try:\n\nmake IN_SOURCE_DIR=<PATH TO SOURCE TRUNK>"; exit 1; fi 
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o plugin.cpp.o -c plugin.cpp

    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o LogicalFile1.cpp.o -c File1/LogicalFile1.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o PhysicalFile1.cpp.o -c File1/PhysicalFile1.cpp

    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o LogicalFile2.cpp.o -c File2/LogicalFile2.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o PhysicalFile2.cpp.o -c File2/PhysicalFile2.cpp

    ### etc.

    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o libname.so \
                               plugin.cpp.o \
                               LogicalFile1.cpp.o \
                               PhysicalFile1.cpp.o \
                               LogicalFile2.cpp.o \
                               PhysicalFile2.cpp.o \
                               ### etc \
                               $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so
```

The biggest issue I have is that there is only one rule (all), and I cannot find an example of a Makefile that does this or how to split it into multiple rules.

Comment: This isn't really a makefile.  It's just a shell script written in makefile format.  Your entire "makefile" is one rule that invokes a shell command that compiles everything.  You might as well have written this as an actual shell script.  I find it hard to believe you can't find an example of a makefile that builds objects one at a time, because _every single example makefile you find_ will do it that way.  That's the *entire* point of using make, rather than a shell script.

Comment: Use autoconf/automake/libtool to generate your makefile. The initial learning curve is a bit painful (not that much, really) but the rewards are worth it. See for example those tutorials: [Building libs with autotools](http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/building_libraries/building_libraries) - [Building with autotools](http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake.shtml) - [Using libs with autotools](http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/using_libraries/using_libraries.shtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's actually pretty straightforward.  Right now, you just have an `all` target that's doing all the building.  You need to break out the compiler invocations and link step into their own rules, and you should be off to the races:

```
BOOST_LOCATION=/usr/local/boost_1_54_0

CFLAGS=-pedantic -W -Wextra -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-long -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -Wno-system-headers -isystem -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -ggdb3  -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
INC=-I. -DPROJECT_ROOT="\"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)\"" -I"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)/include" -I"$(BOOST_LOCATION)"
LIBS=-L"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)/lib" -shared -Wl,-soname,libname.so -L. -lm

all: plugin.cpp.o LogicalFile1.cpp.o PhysicalFile1.cpp.o LogicalFile2.cpp.o PhysicalFile2.cpp.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o libname.so \
                               plugin.cpp.o \
                               LogicalFile1.cpp.o \
                               PhysicalFile1.cpp.o \
                               LogicalFile2.cpp.o \
                               PhysicalFile2.cpp.o \
                               ### etc \
                               $(LIBS)

plugin.cpp.o: plugin.cpp | test
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o plugin.cpp.o -c plugin.cpp

LogicalFile1.cpp.o: File1/LogicalFile1.cpp | test
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o LogicalFile1.cpp.o -c File1/LogicalFile1.cpp

PhysicalFile1.cpp.o: File1/PhysicalFile1.cpp | test
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o PhysicalFile1.cpp.o -c File1/PhysicalFile1.cpp

LogicalFile2.cpp.o: File2/LogicalFile2.cpp | test
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o LogicalFile2.cpp.o -c File2/LogicalFile2.cpp

PhysicalFile2.cpp.o: File2/PhysicalFile2.cpp | test
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o PhysicalFile2.cpp.o -c File2/PhysicalFile2.cpp

test:
    @if test ! -d "$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)"; then echo  "Error. Try:\n\nmake IN_SOURCE_DIR=<PATH TO SOURCE TRUNK>"; exit 1; fi 

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so
```

.PHONY: all clean test

From this point, you can simplify further, too.  You could consolidate all of the compile lines into a single pattern rule, for example.

Comment: I wouldn't use a common name like `test` here, or at least mark it `.PHONY`.

Comment: @user2820044 Try changing a header and invoking make again. It probably won't recompile because this makefile ignores header dependencies.

Comment: I was just going for minimal changes to OP's file.  But adding a `.PHONY` is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use the standard formats and built-in rules for make, you can write your entire makefile as easily as this:

```
ifeq (,$(wildcard $(IN_SOURCE_DIR)/.))
    $(error Try: make IN_SOURCE_DIR=<PATH TO SOURCE TRUNK>)
endif

OBJECTS = plugin.o LogicalFile1.o PhysicalFile1.o LogicalFile2.o PhysicalFile2.o  ### etc
BOOST_LOCATION = /usr/local/boost_1_54_0

CPPFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I. -DPROJECT_ROOT="\"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)\"" -I"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)/include" -I"$(BOOST_LOCATION)"
CXXFLAGS = -pedantic -W -Wextra -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-long -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -Wno-system-headers -isystem -O2 -g -ggdb3
LDFLAGS = -L"$(IN_SOURCE_DIR)/lib" -L.
LDLIBS = -shared -Wl,-soname,libname.so -lm

all: libname.so

libname.so: $(OBJECTS)
        $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: It would be nice if it also automatically built and included dependencies.

Comment: It would be nice to include header dependencies. I think you just need `-MMD` in the flags to generate dependency files, and `-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)` to include them. For bonus points, an empty rule `%.h : ;` will force a recompile when a header is deleted. (Some of that might be specific to gcc/gnumake.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour `-MP` is also useful.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Thanks, I didn't know about that. That looks less hacky than my dummy rule.